# SQL query to select row where current date and time is between fields start and end

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table containing fields with date and time with columns `start` and `end` as DateTime.

[image: Click here for the table screenshot.]

What I want is a query that will select the row where the current date and time is between the value of `start` and `end` fields plus the type is `WE`.

Example:

If current date and time is 2022-05-18 15:30:00, row number 39 should be displayed as a result.

So far, this is the code I came up with but it returns zero result:

```
select * from `examdates` where (NOW() between `start` and `end`) and `type`='WE'
```

I also tried some answers I found in this forum like

```
select * from `examdates` where NOW() >= `start` and NOW() <=`end` and `type`='WE'
```

but result is still

[image: Zero Rows]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the database is in the same timezone as you are? The query should work if the timezones are the same. Use `SELECT NOW();` to see what time the database thinks the current time is.

Comment: Yes, my PHP uses date_default_timezone_set at the beginning

Comment: The database doesn't use PHP's timezone, it has its own timezone.

Comment: Oh I see.. But in PHP, I ran it with a time zone but did not work -> date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
    $timenow=date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $sql=$pdo->query("select * from `examdates` where NOW() >= `start` and NOW() <=`end` and `type`='WE'");

Comment: The query isn't using PHP's time, it's using the database server's time. `NOW()` runs in the database, not PHP. Changing the timezone in PHP has absolutely no effect on it.

Comment: Hmmm... I see.. Is it possible to replace the NOW() with a specific datetime through a variable like $timenow?

Comment: *but it returns zero result* Execute `SELECT NOW();` and ensure does current datetime value is really between the columns values or not.

Comment: Sure, the same way you pass any other variable into a PDO query: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM examdates WHERE :now BETWEEN start AND end"); $stmt->execute([':now' => $timenow]);`

Comment: I think there was an error in the code. The screen went white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `examdates` 
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@time_zone, '+00:00') BETWEEN `start` AND `end`
  and `type`='WE'
```

The function retrieves server timezone info from session variable and converts the server local datetime to GMT time zone. If the values in the table are ones of some another timesone then adjust 3rd function parameter accordingly.

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b054129c8210336d70b6f0a4ecc50b5d

Comment: This worked for me! I just adjusted the 3rd function to +08:00. Thank you @Akina!